# django forloopcounter in template

Tags: python, django, templates

How can i autoincrement a item of my list?

I have something like this:

data = {'port': [22,80,443], 'banner': ['OpenSSH','Apache2','Apache'], 'protocol': ['tcp','tcp','tcp'] }

```
{% for key, value in data.items %}
            <tr>
                 <th class="white">{{key}}</th>
                 <th class="black">{{value.0}}</th>
            </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

How can i autoincrement "value.0" to "value.1", "value.2" etc...

Maybe can i do it with forloop.counter0? But how?

thanks!

Comment: If `value` is a list or dict, you could iterate over it again.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the values using another `for` loop:

```
{% for key, value in ack.items %}
     <tr>
         <th class="white">{{key}}</th>
         {% for v in value %}
             <th class="black">{{v}}</th>
         {% endfor %}
     </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yep, but this is not ordered. For example.
I want the first value of key1 and key2, then i want the second value of the key1 and key2, etc....

Comment: @jstnk can you edit your question to show an example of the intended output?

Comment: Edited.

I want show like this:

-> Port
-> Banner
-> Protocol
-> Port
-> Banner
-> Protocol
-> Port
-> Banner
-> Protocol

Comment: @jstnk Try the update and see if it does what you intend

Comment: this does not work :( {{ack.key.forloop.parentloop.counter}}

Comment: @jstnk Sorry, I missed that. I think you should consider writing a template tag to reorder your data, or do the reordering from your view